# WOFF and WOFF2 mime type support for express js

Tags: node.js, azure, express, web-config, mime-types

I am using express static middle ware to serve my static file to server, facing 404 error for woff2 and woff fonts. This two mime type are available in development environment, but not in production environment. I have hosted my node js app in Azure.

I tried following lines in web.config in Azure server. But whenever I publish my site through GIT Repository URL to the azure, web.config created newly and the below lines are over writes.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" /> 
         </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I need to include mime type support in app.js file of express, So that it will create mime type support in azure web.config.

Comment: Hi kindly try this out `<remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />`